# UICollectionView pagingEnabled position not in place

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I'm trying to do with UICollectionView something like this:

[What am I trying to do - sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGmyu.jpg)

```
myCollectionView.pagingEnabled=YES;
```

Everything works fine, but when the user scrolls the position of the cell is messing up.

Illustrations:

[How I want it to be: in the middle. The mess: on each side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY5GI.png)

Thank You!

Comment: for this you have to make the cell width equal to the collectionView

Comment: But I want a small part of the other two to be on each side, like in the sketch.

Comment: Can you help me please?!?